# Is "knocking on" an idea an idiom for dismissing the idea?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For years, I thought I'd heard others say, "I don't mean to knock on your idea, but..."—and it was definitely *on*, not *down*, although I've heard *knock down* as well—but now that I'm looking it up, I can't seem to find the idiom anywhere. The closest thing I've found is *knock* in the Urban Dictionary as meaning "to disregard, turn down; to ignore,"—but without the preposition *on*.

Have I misheard others all these years?—or have you heard the phrase used this way, too? If *knock on* isn't a real idiom, then is *knock down* the only alternative, or are there similar variations?

Comment: You "can't seem to find the idiom anywhere" because it's not an idiom.

Comment: @mplungjan: Can you add that as an answer so the asker can accept it?

Comment: Ok, done - but it I would consider it GR and I think it will be closed as such

Answer (score 3):

The usage is Knock, not knock on:

[The free dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knock)

> *6.* Slang To find fault with; criticize: *Don't knock the food; it's free.*

and

[Merriam-Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knock)

> *3:* to find fault with *always knocking those in authority*

More here: http://www.onelook.com/?w=knock&ls=a

Comment: In U.S. English, "knock on" does appear idiomatically in connection with _knock_ used in the sense of "a harsh and often petty criticism." Merriam-Webster's, in the link you provide, gives as an example "the knock on him him was that he couldn't handle the pressure." Since the knock is figurative, we might have expected the accompanying preposition to be "against" or "about" or "with regard to," instead of "on."

Comment: I do not agree. It could be written  The *knock*, on him, was...

Answer (score 0):

"Knock on" is indeed an acceptable way of saying "put down the idea/deride the idea/find criticism with the idea".

Though the term "[knock](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knock)" means to find those faults, one doesn't simply say they 'knock' an idea or 'knock down' an idea, which both mean different things.  The idea is that they are deriding the idea by 'knocking on' it, or finding faults with it.

A similar expression would be "I don't mean to rain on your parade" to say you do not mean to ruin a person's day with bad news.

Comment: Yes one does say knock an idea. Don't knock it if you haven't tried it